# Application.Exit after Application.Run doesn't work

Tags: c#, winforms

Context: the application I'm trying to make does not display a form initially, but only an open file dialog. After selecting a file the application may exit or open a form.

I'm having trouble closing my application after calling Application.Run(). The following example does not produce an application that kills itself.

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        var context = new Context();
        Application.Run(context);
        Console.Beep();
    }
}

class Context : ApplicationContext
{
    public Context()
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
}
```

On a side note, what preparations do I need to make before I can open a form? Do I need to have a call to Application.Run before I can show forms?

Thanks a bunch! XOXO

Comment: But in this code, you're calling `Exit()` *before* `Run()`.

Comment: You're right. So how do I let the exit call run after the run call? Can I send the exit call to the message loop that Application.Run() executes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try moving the exit logic to a new method:

```
class Context : ApplicationContext 
{ 
  public void Exit() 
  { 
    Application.Exit(); 
  } 
}
```

and have `Application.Run` call `context.Exit()` when needed

The problem with the original approach is that you placed the exit logic in the constructor of `Context`, which means every time you create a `Context` object, you have the potential to exit your program (it is a certainty in the case of the code you posted).  Instead have `Context` capture all relevant (context) information and make the decision to exit based on that info when an explicit method call is made after it was created.

Answer (score 3):

```
var context = new Context();
```

With this statment your application executes Application.Exit(); after that your statement Application.Run executes. This could be the reason